# Plotting the integral of a probability distribution in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the integral of probability distribution, similar to this image: [image: prob]

Notice how the Y-axis starts becoming more granular towards the top.

I already have the exact percentiles that I want to plot, and the corresponding values for the x-axis.

My code so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats

x = np.array([0.0000025,0.000005,0.00001,0.00002,0.00003,0.00004,0.00005,0.00006,0.00007,0.00008,0.00009,0.0001,0.0002,0.00025,0.00035,0.0005,0.001,0.002,0.005,0.01,1])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46.29821447,49.49781571,49.83072758,50.89081787,98.49113721,98.5522082,99.29547499,99.91765345,99.93779431,99.95351796,99.98066963,99.99294867,100])
my_xticks = ['<2.5 uS', '<5 uS', '<10 uS', '<20 uS', '<30 uS', '<40 uS', '<50 uS', '<60 uS', '<70 uS', '<80 uS', '<90 uS', '<100 uS', '<200 uS', '<250 uS', '<350 uS', '<500 uS', '<1 mS', '<2 uS', '<5 mS', '<10 mS', '<1 S']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.yticks(np.arange(y.min() - 20, y.max() + 1, 10))
plt.xticks(np.arange(x.min() + 0.035, x.max(), 0.08))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

Which outputs this:

[image: output]

**Update**

So I managed to split multiple plots 10 to be precise while assigning different y-axis limitations to each in order to spread my data points apart for readability. This is all hard coded which presents its own challenges because I will feed dynamic data with different vectors being really close in values. I could engineer function to analyze the proximity of the values to each other, based on that have it plot x amount of plots and assign limitations, but this is excessive on work and resources having to plot multiple plots. Here is what I have so far,

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46.29821447,49.49781571,49.83072758,50.89081787,98.49113721,98.5522082,99.29547499,99.91765345,99.93779431,99.95351796,99.98066963,99.99294867,100])
my_xticks = ['<2.5 uS', '<5 uS', '<10 uS', '<20 uS', '<30 uS', '<40 uS', '<50 uS', '<60 uS', '<70 uS', '<80 uS', '<90 uS', '<100 uS', '<200 uS', '<250 uS', '<350 uS', '<500 uS', '<1 mS', '<2 uS', '<5 mS', '<10 mS', '<1 S']
f,(ax,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9,ax10) = plt.subplots(10,1,sharex=True)

majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%.7f')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
ax.grid(axis='y')
ax2.grid(axis='y')
ax3.grid(axis='y')
ax4.grid(axis='y')
ax5.grid(axis='y')
ax6.grid(axis='y')
ax7.grid(axis='y')
ax8.grid(axis='y')
ax9.grid(axis='y')
ax10.grid(axis='y')

ax.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax.plot(x,y, '.')
ax2.plot(x,y, '.')
ax2.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax3.plot(x,y, '.')
ax3.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax4.plot(x,y, '.')
ax4.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax5.plot(x,y, '.')
ax5.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax6.plot(x,y, '.')
ax6.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax7.plot(x,y, '.')
ax7.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax8.plot(x,y, '.')
ax8.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax9.plot(x,y, '.')
ax9.plot(x,y, '-r')
ax10.plot(x,y, '.')
ax10.plot(x,y, '-r')

ax.set_yticks(y)
ax2.set_yticks(y)
ax3.set_yticks(y)
ax4.set_yticks(y)
ax5.set_yticks(y)
ax6.set_yticks(y)
ax7.set_yticks(y)
ax8.set_yticks(y)
ax9.set_yticks(y)
ax10.set_yticks(y)

ax.set_ylim(99.95,100)
ax2.set_ylim(99.8,99.95)
ax3.set_ylim(99.5,99.8)
ax4.set_ylim(99,99.5)
ax5.set_ylim(98.5,99)
ax6.set_ylim(93,98.5)
ax7.set_ylim(90,93)
ax8.set_ylim(86,90)
ax9.set_ylim(70,86)
ax10.set_ylim(0,70)

ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax4.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax4.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax5.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax5.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax6.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax6.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax7.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax7.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax8.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax8.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax9.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax9.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax10.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax3.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax4.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax5.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax6.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax7.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax8.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax9.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax10.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)

plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: I saw data when I plotted it on a loglog scale (i.e. replacing `plt.plot(x,y)` with `plt.loglog(x,y)`)

Comment: I also strongly recommend using `pyplot` instead of `pylab`, i.e. `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`. `pyplot` contains only plotting-related code from matplotlib, whereas `pylab` also imports the *entire contents* of numpy, which introduces a huge amount of irrelevant clutter to the module namespace.

Answer (score 3):

*y* increases from 0 at *x* = 0.00006, to 99.99 at *x* = 0.01, then only increases by a further ~0.007 between *x* = 0.01 and *x* = 1. The line basically shoots straight up in an L-shape that is so close to the left-hand and upper borders of the plot that it is obscured by the axes.

If you set your axis limits slightly wider:

```
plt.xlim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.ylim(-10, 110)
```

then you can easily see what's happening:

[image]

As @snorthway commented, it might be more sensible to plot this data on log-log scales (as in the example image you showed):

```
plt.loglog(x, y)
```

[image]

However you will then run into the issue that your *y*-values contain 0s. Since log(0) = -infinity, the line becomes vertical for *x* < 0.00007.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, I will be doing more experimentation. All I need to plot is the percentages which are the y-axis:
    `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46.29821447,49.49781571,49.83072758,50.89081787,98.49113721,98.5522082,99.29547499,99.91765345,99.93779431,99.95351796,99.98066963,99.99294867,100`

and the the x-axis values are just latency's(time in micro/milliseconds):

`'<2.5 uS', '<5 uS', '<10 uS', '<20 uS', '<30 uS', '<40 uS', '<50 uS', '<60    uS', '<70 uS', '<80 uS', '<90 uS', '<100 uS', '<200 uS', '<250 uS', '<350 uS', '<500 uS', '<1 mS', '<2 uS', '<5 mS', '<10 mS', '<1 S'`

Comment: So I managed to plot multiple subplots and stitch them together while assigning different limitations for each one. The problem with this is resources are increased in plotting multiple plots as well as if I have dynamic data as the input it won't properly separate the new data. I can most likely engineer a dynamic function that detects values relations and assign dynamic limitations for each plot but there has to be a different easier way of just spreading the values that are close too each other. Here is my graph,
[img](http://i.imgur.com/LkXeLsZ.png?1)

Comment: The comments aren't really the right place to discuss this. Could you please ask this as a new question? You provide a link to this one for context.

Comment: sorry about that, so I figured out since I'm overriding the x and y tick labels  all I have to do is alter my actual y values that are similar. Which helps me not having to deal with multiple plots. That question is posted here,
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708479/amplify-values-that-are-similar-using-numpy-or-scipy-in-python)

Comment: I meant to put a link in your new question that points to this one