# Amplify values that are similar using Numpy or Scipy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a numpy array that is being plotted using Matplotlib. My issue is that the values are very similar, so when it is graphed the readability is non existent.

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46.29821447,49.49781571,49.83072758,50.89081787,98.49113721,98.5522082,99.29547499,99.91765345,99.93779431,99.95351796,99.98066963,99.99294867,100
```

Notice how some of the values are clustered, My question is there any method to iterate over the numpy array and determine those close knit clusters and then apply a amplification that separates them excluding the zero values? When I graph them in Matplotlib this is the graph [image: graph]

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46.29821447,49.49781571,49.83072758,50.89081787,98.49113721,98.5522082,99.29547499,99.91765345,99.93779431,99.95351796,99.98066963,99.99294867,100])
my_xticks = ['<2.5 uS', '<5 uS', '<10 uS', '<20 uS', '<30 uS', '<40 uS', '<50 uS', '<60 uS', '<70 uS', '<80 uS', '<90 uS', '<100 uS', '<200 uS', '<250 uS', '<350 uS', '<500 uS', '<1 mS', '<2 uS', '<5 mS', '<10 mS', '<1 S']
my_yticks = [0,20,40,60,80,90,95,98,99,99.7,99.9,99.97,99.99,99.997,99.999,99.9997,99.9999,99.99999,99.999999]
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([0,20,40,60,80,90,95,98,99,99.7,99.9,99.97,99.99,99.997,99.999,99.9997,99.9999,99.99999,99.999999])
plt.yticks(y, my_yticks)
plt.plot(x,y, '-r')
plt.plot(x,y, '.')
plt.ylim(bottom=-5, top=105)
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.xlabel('Latency in Micro Milli Second')
plt.ylabel('Probability in %')
plt.title('Probability Distribution')
plt.show()
```

Above is my code, I guess what I'm looking for is a bucket sort algorithm, where if certain values are x amount close to each other increase their values by x amount so when I graph the newly generated array, the points in the graph that were really close to each other, since we added x amount to them in the new array, are now spread apart and are more readable.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code a bit for getting the same graph above with 15 different plots composing the same graph.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21])
# Need to create a function that detects similar values to the first 2 digits 49.x 49.x 99.x 99.x and takes the min and max and assigns it to ylim dynamically
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46.29821447,49.49781571,49.83072758,50.89081787,98.49113721,98.5522082,99.29547499,99.91765345,99.93779431,99.95351796,99.98066963,99.99294867,100])
#override x ticks with latency labels
my_xticks = ['<2.5 uS', '<5 uS', '<10 uS', '<20 uS', '<30 uS', '<40 uS', '<50 uS', '<60 uS', '<70 uS', '<80 uS', '<90 uS', '<100 uS', '<200 uS', '<250 uS', '<350 uS', '<500 uS', '<1 mS', '<2 uS', '<5 mS', '<10 mS', '<1 S']
f,(ax,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9,ax10,ax11,ax12,ax13,ax14,ax15) = plt.subplots(15,1,sharex=True)
#plot array to iterate over and assign different matplot properties for the graph
plotArray = ax,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9,ax10,ax11,ax12,ax13,ax14,ax15
#adjust the value formatter to read upto 7 decimal points 99.xxxxxxx
majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%.7f')
#adjust the vertical spacing between each plot to 0 to stitch them together (no space)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
#override x tick labels with custom latency labels
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
# start a for loop targeting the 15 different plots to assign properties.
for var, i in enumerate(plotArray):
    #Y-axis grid lines
    i.grid(axis='y')
    #red line
    i.plot(x,y, '-r')
    #points for each value
    i.plot(x,y, '.')
    #over ride y tick labels to only show the tick labels of each data point
    i.set_yticks(y)
    #override value format on yaxis to read 7 decimal points
    i.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
    #first plot
    if i is (plotArray[0]):
        i.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
        i.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom='off', top='on', labelbottom='off')
    #last plot
    elif i is (plotArray[-1]):
        i.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom='on', top='off', labelbottom='on')
        i.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
        i.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    #inbetween plots
    else:
        i.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
        i.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        i.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom='off', top='off', labelbottom='off')

# Values should be dynamiclly assigned due to different cluster values which are graphed on top of each other
ax.set_ylim(99.95,100)
ax2.set_ylim(99.8,99.95)
ax3.set_ylim(99.5,99.8)
ax4.set_ylim(99,99.5)
ax5.set_ylim(98.5,99)
ax6.set_ylim(98,98.5)
ax7.set_ylim(90,98)
ax8.set_ylim(86,90)
ax9.set_ylim(70,86)
ax10.set_ylim(60,70)
ax11.set_ylim(50,60)
ax12.set_ylim(45,50)
ax13.set_ylim(40,45)
ax14.set_ylim(30,40)
ax15.set_ylim(0,30)

plt.show()
```

I need to be able to go over the array that are my percentages which will vary.

`0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46.29821447,49.49781571,49.83072758,50.89081787,98.49113721,98.5522082,99.29547499,99.91765345,99.93779431,99.95351796,99.98066963,99.99294867,100`

In order to assign dynamic Y axis limitations to the graph to insure that the data points in my array are displayed in each plot properly.

1. Go over array and get values that are very close ie 49.x 49.x 98.x 98.x 99.x 99.x
2. capture those numbers and for each set calculate the value thats highest and smallest ie if I have 4 values for one set 99.9995 99.99 99.9994 99.993394 it would output (99.99, 99.9995) for that set and then I can assign that to a yaxis limitation for one of the plots out of the 15 to capture those points and make sure that they are spread apart on the graph and readable.

Comment: What does it mean to "apply a amplification"? Also, can you post your code?

Comment: You might consider plotting the CDF in separate sections using broken y-axes.  [Here's an example from the matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html).

Comment: How is it on a logarithmic plot?

Comment: @cphlewis He asked a closely related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662432/plotting-the-integral-of-a-probability-distribution-in-matplotlib), see my answer for a log-log plot

Comment: so I already have a probability percentages being return in a array, so I'm just trying to plot that ie I don't need to do any calculations, I just need to plot the data.

Comment: @ali_m I tried to do the broken y axis, but since my probability percentages vary in how close they are to each other in the overall array ex: I could have clusters in the lower ranges like 45.6, 45.7 or 99.95 99.99, I can't pass dynamic data to the plot since the graph will still be unreadable due to those values being so close to one another.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "dynamic data". What particular features about the CDF are most important for you to represent? For example, you might be more interested in showing the overall shape, or you might want to discriminate precisely between particular nearby quantiles. There's not going to be a single way to plot this CDF that is ideal from every perspective.

Comment: @ali_m Thank you for helping me out on this. I just need to make my data "readable" meaning they can't be on top of each other. I have created a graph with 15 different plots each with different y_limits. The problem is that if I pass in different arrays those numbers that are close can vary either in the upper ranges or lower ranges of my array thats passed in. So in order for this current method to work I need a way to analyze the array, detech those (49.x 49.x) lower or if the are higher (99.x 99.x). Check the update to this question.

Comment: Have you tried a log scale?  That will allow you to get some separation on your y axis over large changes

Comment: I have and the values are still too close this is the graph that I get notice that the points are still too close to distinguish them. [Log Graph](http://i.imgur.com/xbgqrNv.png?1)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much impossible to plot data like this in such a way as to accurately represent both the fine-scale differences between quantiles and the large-scale jumps. You can mess around with having a discontinuous y-axis, but eventually when you end up having to apply all kinds of non-linearities in order to fit the data onto your axes then it becomes very difficult to interpret the plot.

Is there some very important reason why you have to plot the [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), rather than the [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)?

Here's what the PDF of your data actually looks like on semi-log axes:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x = np.array([2.5E-06, 5.0E-06, 1.0E-05, 2.0E-05, 3.0E-05, 4.0E-05, 5.0E-05,
              6.0E-05, 7.0E-05, 8.0E-05, 9.0E-05, 1.0E-04, 2.0E-04, 2.5E-04,
              3.5E-04, 5.0E-04, 1.0E-03, 2.0E-03, 5.0E-03, 1.0E-02, 1.0E+00])

y = np.array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
              46.29821447, 49.49781571, 49.83072758, 50.89081787,
              98.49113721, 98.5522082 , 99.29547499, 99.91765345,
              99.93779431, 99.95351796, 99.98066963, 99.99294867,  100.]) / 100.

# we can get a rough estimate the PDF from the derivative of the CDF using
# second-order central differences (it would be better to evaluate the PDF
# directly if you can)
dx = np.gradient(x)
dy = np.gradient(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.fill_between(x, 0, (dy / dx), alpha=0.5)

ax.set_ylabel('Probability density')
ax.set_xlabel('S')
```

[image]

In my opinion the PDF gives a much clearer intuition of what's going on. Basically you have a high probability density for values close to ~70uS, a smaller peak around ~100uS, then almost zero probability everywhere else.

As you can see these peaks in the PDF are very sharp, which means that when you compute the CDF (integral) you end up with lots of quantiles that are very similar, then huge jumps corresponding to where most of the probability density is.

The jumps in the CDF (corresponding to the peaks in the PDF) are probably the most salient features of the probability distribution to represent, since they reflect the values that you are most likely to sample.